# Rewrite Rule for jsp

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, rules

I have this URL:

```
https://www.example.com/folder/New.jsp?par=new1
```

which I want to redirect to:

```
https://www.example.com/folder/New.jsp
```

how should I do that?

Basically, I have `par=new1|new2|new3|new4` that would need to be redirected to `https://www.example.com/folder/New.jsp`

I did several attempts but those were not successful.

Answer (score 1):

Well, at the start of New.jsp you can just do

```
<%
    String par = request.getParameter("par");
    if (null != par && par.matches("new[1-4]")) {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getRequestURI());
        return;
    }
%>
```

Comment: Hi! Christoffer. thanks for your response. Is this something that can be done in .htaccess instead?

Comment: .htaccess is an Apache feature, and Apache does not run JSPs. You might want to try this question at http://serverfault.com/ instead.